# How to slide a div from left to right on the image slide show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to javascript and jquery. I have downloaded fadeslide show. i am fine with the slide show.But the description for each image is sliding on image from the bottom. But i need it from left. So kindly help me.

code is as below.

showhidedescpanel:function(state, animateduration){
  var setting=this.setting
  var endpoint=(state=="show")? setting.dimensions[1]-setting.panelheight : this.setting.dimensions[1]
  setting.$descpanel.stop().animate({top:endpoint}, (typeof animateduration!="undefined"? animateduration : fadeSlideShow_descpanel.slidespeed), function(){
   if (setting.descreveal=="always" && state=="hide")
    setting.$restorebutton.css({visibility:'visible'}) //show restore button
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
showhidedescpanel:
```

function(state, animateduration){ var setting=this.setting var endpoint=(state=="show")? setting.dimensions[1]-setting.panelWidth : -this.setting.dimensions[1] setting.$descpanel.stop().animate({left:endpoint}, (typeof animateduration!="undefined"? animateduration : fadeSlideShow_descpanel.slidespeed), function(){ if (setting.descreveal=="always" && state=="hide") setting.$restorebutton.css({visibility:'visible'})  })

try this. Since code is not complete and i cannot do much help.